# Identify the most recent date before another date from another column per group using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe structured like so:

```
example <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                         delivereddate = c("7/20/2019","7/24/2019","7/28/2019","3/24/2019","4/13/2019","4/25/2019","11/13/2019","11/20/2019","11/27/2019"),
                         applieddate = c("7/22/2019","7/22/2019","7/22/2019",NA,NA,NA,"11/21/2019","11/21/2019","11/21/2019"))
```

I am attempting to add a column that identifies the most recent deliverdate before the applieddate for each id. An example of what I'm trying to get for the final result is the following:

```
desiredresult <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                            delivereddate = c("7/20/2019","7/24/2019","7/28/2019","3/24/2019","4/13/2019","4/25/2019","11/13/2019","11/20/2019","11/27/2019"),
                            applieddate = c("7/22/2019","7/22/2019","7/22/2019",NA,NA,NA,"11/21/2019","11/21/2019","11/21/2019"),
                            applied = c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0))
```

I need the applied column to be binary(0 or 1) and there can only be 1 row per id with a 1 flag. If an id has no applieddate, then the applied flag is 0 for all rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `findInterval`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
example %>% 
      dplyr::group_by(id) %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(applied = +(row_number() %in% 
              findInterval(lubridate::mdy(first(applieddate)), 
                          lubridate::mdy(delivereddate))))
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
#     id delivereddate applieddate applied
#  <dbl> <chr>         <chr>         <int>
#1     1 7/20/2019     7/22/2019         1
#2     1 7/24/2019     7/22/2019         0
#3     1 7/28/2019     7/22/2019         0
#4     2 3/24/2019     <NA>              0
#5     2 4/13/2019     <NA>              0
#6     2 4/25/2019     <NA>              0
#7     3 11/13/2019    11/21/2019        0
#8     3 11/20/2019    11/21/2019        1
#9     3 11/27/2019    11/21/2019        0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the columns to date class, subtract `applieddate` from `delivereddate` and take the absolute value. For each `id` we then assign 1 to index where minimum difference is observed.

```
library(dplyr)

example %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('date'), lubridate::mdy), 
         applied = abs(delivereddate - applieddate)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(applied = +(row_number() %in% which.min(applied)))

#     id delivereddate applieddate applied
#  <dbl> <date>        <date>        <int>
#1     1 2019-07-20    2019-07-22        1
#2     1 2019-07-24    2019-07-22        0
#3     1 2019-07-28    2019-07-22        0
#4     2 2019-03-24    NA                0
#5     2 2019-04-13    NA                0
#6     2 2019-04-25    NA                0
#7     3 2019-11-13    2019-11-21        0
#8     3 2019-11-20    2019-11-21        1
#9     3 2019-11-27    2019-11-21        0
```